# Validate an HTML number input

Tags: javascript

How can I validate a field that must contain 1.00 or greater? Also must contain 2 decimal points.

I have found this....

```
    <input pattern="\d?\d\.\d\d" maxlength=5 size=5 onchange="check(this)">
    <script>
    function check(elem) {
      if(!elem.value.match(/^\d?\d\.\d\d$/)) {
        alert('Error in data – use the format dd.dd (d = digit)');
      }
    }
    </script>
```

but it doesn't permit anything more than 99.99.

Sorry I need to add more details to explain this.

I need to accept 1.00 or 10.00 or even 1000.00

just not

1 or 10 or 2.0 or 20.0

It needs to be a whole number and 2 decimal places

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the `input maxlength=5` is not preventing higher than 99.99 since it's already 5 characters in length?

Comment: Yes sorry I have increased that with no results

Answer (score 2):

`/^[1-9]+\d*\.\d{2}$/g` should work where

```
^[1-9] : makes sure the non-decimal part is greater than 0.
\d*    : allows trailing zeroes as in 1000
```

```js
const regex = /^[1-9]+\d*\.\d{2}$/g;
const str = `1601.91`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: `/^\d*[123456789]+\.\d{2}$/g` would be helpful in case there is a 0 digit to the left of the decimal.

Comment: `[123456789]+` - Huh? So you will not allow `10.00` but will allow `11.00`?

Comment: why `[123456789]` instead of `[1-9]`

Comment: `regex = /^[1-9]+0*\.\d{2}$/g;` only allows 0s directly to the left of the decimal (it would fail on something like `str = 1601.19`. Try something like `regex = /^\d*[1-9]+\d*\.\d{2}$/g`. This will allow leading 0s, though.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help